# Relatório no Report View tipo Mestre-Detalhe

Tags: c#

Caros coletas,

Estou desenvolvendo um relatório através do Report View do tipo mestre-detalhe. A fonte de dados deste relatório será um arquivo texto. Já está praticamente pronto. O problema está no momento de transferir os dados da parte do detalhe para o relatório. o problema está na área do detalhe onde serão exibidos vários itens. Por enquanto para teste e facilitar o desenvolvimento do código inclui uma única ocorrência, mas está ocorrência está se repetindo várias vezes. Não estou conseguindo fazer com que está occorrência seja exibida somente uma vez. A lógica que criei é ler o arquivo texto, alimentar uma lista, da lista transferir para uma classe e da classe para o dataset do relatório. Não sei se é a lógica ideal mas como estou aprendendo a programar com C# é o que me inspirou nas pesquisas que fiz. Espero ter sido claro e colocado todas as informações importantes. Obrigado.

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace OrdemProducao
{
    public partial class FrmOrdemProducao : Form
    {
        static string linha;
        static string resultado;
        static int ix;

```
    List<string> lista = new List<string>();

    DadosOrdemProducao op = new DadosOrdemProducao();

    public FrmOrdemProducao()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void reportViewer1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\SACTRM\\ORDEM.TXT");

        while ((linha = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Processa(linha);

            if resultado != "")
            {
                lista.Add(resultado);
            }
        }

        var DadosRelatorio = (from item in lista
                              select new DadosOrdemProducao()
                              {
                                  OrdemProducaoId = int.Parse(lista[0]),
                                  DescricaoProduto = lista[1],
        //ESTES SÃO OS CAMPOS DE DETALHE
                                  MatprimaDescricao = lista[2],
                                  MatprimaQuantidade = lista[3],
                                  MatprimaLote = lista[4]
                              }).ToArray();

        var DataSource = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("DataSetOrdemProducao", DadosRelatorio);

        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(DataSource);

        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }

    public void Processa(string linha)
    {
        resultado = "";

        if (linha.Contains("ORDEM"))
        {
            resultado = linha.Substring(6);

        }

        if (linha.Contains("PRODUTO"))
        {
            resultado = linha.Substring(8);

        }

        if (linha.Contains("DESCRICAOMATPRIMA"))
        {
            resultado = linha.Substring(18);

        }

        if (linha.Contains("QTDEMATPRIMA"))
        {
            resultado = linha.Substring(13);
        }

        if (linha.Contains("LOTEMATPRIMA"))
        {
            resultado = linha.Substring(13);
        }
    }
}
```

}